# Prevent View resizing near the right edge of RelativeLayout

Tags: android, view

How to prevent `View` resizing near the right edge of `RelativeLayout`. The part of the `View` should settled out of the screen. The code like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(-2,-2);
params.leftMargin = posx;
params.topMargin = posy;
SomeView.setLayoutParams(params);
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(Context);
layout.addView(SomeView);
```

Comment: explain a bit more or add an image. "The part of the View should settled out of the screen", what does this mean ? Like NavigationDrawer ?

Comment: please elaborate more and post your xml